# How can I use shell builtin type command in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, shell, popen

I am trying to create an application which will have a different result on Debian based system with dpkg package manager, Arch based system with pacman package manager and Redhat based system with yum package manager or rpm package manager.

To detect the system, I am using `Kernel#system` method primarily there.

Nevertheless this works:

```
%x(which pacman)        # => "/usr/bin/pacman\n"
%x(which dpkg)          # => ""
system('which pacman')  # => true    # and perhaps better to redirect stdout to /dev/null
system('which dpkg')    # => false
```

But I don't like to use `which` because it's not a builtin. That said, your package manager can remove `which` (`pacman -R which`) or you may be missing which.

In that case, I would love to use `type -p`

In BASH or sh:

```
$ type -p pacman
/usr/bin/pacman
$ echo $?
0

$ type -p dpkg
$ echo $?
1
```

But in Ruby:

```
> system('type -p pacman')
# => nil

> system('type -p dpkg')
# => nil

> %x('type -p pacman')
sh: type -p pacman: command not found
# => ""

# OR
> require 'open3'
# => true

> Open3.capture2e('type -p pacman')
Traceback (most recent call last):
        7: from /home/sourav/.irb:350:in `<main>'
        6: from (irb):7
        5: from (irb):7:in `rescue in irb_binding'
        4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:390:in `capture2e'
        3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:208:in `popen2e'
        2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:213:in `popen_run'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:213:in `spawn'
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - type)

> IO.popen('type -p pacman')
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /home/sourav/.irb:350:in `<main>'
        3: from (irb):6
        2: from (irb):6:in `rescue in irb_binding'
        1: from (irb):6:in `popen'
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - type)
```

Same goes with `PTY#spawn`, `exec`, `Kernel#```

How can I use the `type -p` command in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your command by first spawning a new shell:

```
system('sh -c "type -p pry"')
/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/pry
=> true
```

And likewise get `false` when it isn't found:

```
system('sh -c "type -p qwertyasdf"')
=> false
```

Comment: That works. But why does system('type -p pry') fail?

Comment: Because you can’t run shell builtins outside a shell instance.

Comment: Doesn't `%x` syntax or `Kernel#system` already run your command in a shell? Why does `%x` warn about `sh: type -p hi: command not found` if not a shell is already running?

Comment: Good question. Also, on my Mac, `%x(type -p which)` works (and indeed `%x(type type)` says "type is a shell builtin"), whereas they do fail on Linux as OP says. (The Mac version is 2.7 preview though, don't have an older one to test now if it's because of the version bump).